# How to concat two columns value like - product_name(product_quantity), ..... from table in while loop and store in a variable

Tags: php, mysql, function

I have a table with two columns : product_name and product_qty with multiple rows

I want output as:

product_name(product_qty).........

like this one

product_one(2), product_two(4), product_three(1)

I'm trying by this method :

```
require 'config.php';
$grand_total = 0;
$items = array();
$qty = array();
$allItems ='';
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM cart");
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    $grand_total +=$row['total_price'];
    $items[] = $row['product_name'];
    $qty[] = $row['qty'];
}
$array = array_combine($items, $qty);
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    $allItems .= $key."(".$value."), ";
}
```

And getting output as :
product_one(2), product_two(4), product_three(1),

but I don't want comma in last......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, the answer is in your question title. :), just as below:

```
select concat(product_name,'(',product_qty,')') as result from my_table;
```

And the data example see below:

```
mysql> select * from my_table;
+---------------+-------------+
| product_name  | product_qty |
+---------------+-------------+
| product_one   |           2 |
| product_two   |           4 |
| product_three |           1 |
+---------------+-------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select concat(product_name,'(',product_qty,')') as result from my_table;
+------------------+
| result           |
+------------------+
| product_one(2)   |
| product_two(4)   |
| product_three(1) |
+------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: can we do this by using any array function of php??

Comment: Of course we can, you can just `select` the product_name and product_qty columns ,and use the join string method which supplied by php to join the result into the `product_name(product_qty)` format. I'm not familiar with php, but the string join function of php must be simple.

Comment: @Wolfmania there is no need `foreach` and  `array_combine` Now check my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using [CONCAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) function

SELECT CONCAT(`product_name`, ' ', `product_qty`) FROM `table`

No Need to use foreach and array_combine all. From query itself you can fetch data as you need. Check below your update code

```
$grand_total = 0;
$sqlStmt = "SELECT CONCAT(product_name, '(', product_qty,')') AS ItemQty,total_price FROM cart";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sqlStmt);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    $grand_total +=$row['total_price'];
    $items[] = $row['ItemQty'];
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($items);
print_r($grand_total);
```

Sample output

> ```
> Array (
> [0] => product_one(2)
> [1] => product_two(4)
> [2] => product_one(2)
> [3] => product_two(4)
> [4] => product_three(1) ) 1700
> ```